# Flask MySqldb Error: ""execute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'"

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I've been trying to connect to a MySql database to create user accounts. I am using a MySQL procedure to insert into the DB. I keep getting the error in the title. I am using mysqldb flask extension Here is my Python code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flask.ext.mysqldb import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'database'
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/showSignUp')
def showSignUp():
    return render_template('signup.html')

@app.route('/signUp', methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    try:
        _name = request.form['inputName']
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password:   
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
            _hashed_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
            cursor.callproc('sp_createUser',(_name,_email,_hashed_password))
            data = cursor.fetchall()

            if len(data) is 0:
              cursor.execute()
              return json.dump({'message':'User created successfully'})
            else:
              return json.dump({'error 1':str(data[0])})
        else:
            return json.dump({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    except Exception as e:
      return json.dumps({'error 2':str(e)})
    finally:
      cursor.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And my procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_createUser`(
    IN p_name VARCHAR(45),
    IN p_username VARCHAR(45),
    IN p_password VARCHAR(256)
)
BEGIN
    if ( select exists (select 1 from tbl_user where user_username = p_username) ) THEN

        select 'Username Exists !!';

    ELSE

        insert into tbl_user
        (
            user_name,
            user_username,
            user_password
        )
        values
        (
            p_name,
            p_username,
            p_password
        );

    END IF;
END
```

Comment: `cursor.execute()` can only execute a query, you didn't pass one in..

Comment: Also, don't use `is` on integers! That `is 0` works at all is a coincidence due to an optimisation in CPython. **Always** use `== 0`. In this case `if data:` is enough however, since an empty list is false in a boolean test.

Comment: In this case, I want the procedure to execute the insert. `cursor.commit()` does not work.  Noted on the second point. Thanks.

Comment: Then use `connection.commit()`? `cursor.execute()` won't do that, you *already* executed the stored procedure.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using a stored procedure instead of using a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `user_username` column?

Comment: I am  following a blogpost on tutsplus.com. It used a procedure. New to Flask here. The guide is using `flask-mysql` but that doesn't work on Python 3 so I switched to `flask-mysqldb` which is severely lacking in documentation.

When I added `mysql.connection.commit()` I get `"'Connection' object is not callable`

Comment: I'd switch to another tutorial then. Using a stored procedure to solve a problem that can be solved with built-in SQL features shows a lack of expertise with databases that is very worrying.

Comment: Also, I'd look at SQLAlchemy instead, which is far more powerful than plain SQL (although you can still use plain SQL with it) and you can switch databases almost at will too. The integration with Flask is well-maintained, Python 3 compatible and widely covered in tutorials.

Comment: Yeah I don't like it, I was thinking I should get this to work first, then switch to a built-in solution. Trying to minimize moving parts I guess.

Update: Ok I'll look into alchemy. Thanks!